# Como asignar id dinamicos

Tags: javascript, ajax

como puedo asignar un id dinamico a un boton que imprimo en un while? necesito asignarle un id dinamico para poder hacer la insersion, ya que no poseo formulario.

aqui el codigo

```
        while($fila=$consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
             $this->empleados[]=$filas;
             $Filas = consult_cedula($fila['Persona']);

             echo "<tr>";
             echo '<td>' . $Filas['codsucursal'] . '</td>';
             echo '<td>' . $fila['Persona'] . '</td>';
             echo '<td>' . $fila['Fecha'] . '</td>';
             echo '<td>' . $fila['Hora'] . '</td>';
             echo '<td>' . $Filas['nombre'] . '</td>';
             echo '<td>' . $Filas['cargo'] . '</td>';

             echo '<td>' . '<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn" value="..." data-fech="' .
             $fila['Fecha'] . '" data-hora="' . $fila['Hora'] . '" data-ced="' . $fila['Persona'] .
             '" data-nom="' . $Filas['nombre'] . '" data-cargo="' . $Filas['cargo'] . '">';
             echo "</tr>";
```

Comment: Coloca un contador y cada vez que pase un ciclo en el while lo aumentas, y puedes colocarlo id="btn-".$contador."...., de ésa manera luego sabes que el btn-0 es el primer botón, btn-1 el segundo y así vas...

Comment: Etiquetas AJAX y Javascript... ¿pero esto es php, no?

Answer (score 1):

Como ya se ha dicho en comentarios, puedes usar un contador, en este caso `$i`, que inicializas a 1 antes de entrar en el `while`, usando ese valor para dar el `id` al botón en cada paso del bucle.

También, puedes darle más claridad a tu código usando una variable que vaya concatenando el contenido que quieres mostrar, y haciendo `echo` de esa variable solamente al final. Del mismo modo, podría darle más claridad al código emplear variables para los diferentes valores que presentas en la tabla, mucho más si algunos de esos valores son usados más de una vez.

El código quedaría así:

```
/*Variable única para ir concatenando todo el contenido HTML*/
$strHTML="";
/*Contador que se irá incrementando*/
$i = 1;

while ($i <= 10) {
    $strHTML.="<tr>";
    $codSucursal=$Filas['codsucursal'];
    $persona=$fila['Persona'];
    $fecha=$fila['Fecha'];
    $hora=$fila['Hora'];              
    $nombre=$Filas['nombre'];
    $cargo=$Filas['cargo'];

    $strHTML.="<td>$codSucursal</td>";
    $strHTML.="<td>$persona</td>";
    $strHTML.="<td>$fecha</td>";
    $strHTML.="<td>$hora</td>";
    $strHTML.="<td>$nombre</td>";
    $strHTML.="<td>$cargo</td>";
    $strHTML.="<td>".'<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-'.$i.'" value="..." 
               data-fech="' .$fecha . '" data-hora="' . $hora . '" data-ced="' . $persona .
               '" data-nom="' . $nombre . '" data-cargo="' . $cargo . '"></td>';
    $strHTML.= "</tr>";
    $i++;
}
/*Imprimimos una sola vez el contenido*/
echo $strHTML;
```

Comment: uuyyy buenisimo .. me gusta mucho .. gracias amigo